# Cant Access Contract - Mist

Tags: mist, myetherwallet

Last year just after the DAO hack i started to play with ETH and MIST, i created a contract because i wanted to see the transaction info of the wallet i wanted to use for mining..

I have updated mist, but i do not see the contract in my wallet anymore, i can see the address on the blockchain with eth on it, and i can see a Contract Creation on the main address on the mist wallet but i do not have have the contract listed

I have tried to upload the keyfile to myether but there is 0 eth there, and nothing under token...?

Comment: Also when i created the contract i do not remember getting any kind of output to keep like a ABI or anything, here is the address - https://etherscan.io/address/0x986b2062ffe6505b8ffd6f5ca3d377d8d4b3ecce